# Looking for an one-way function with small input and long output

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography, entropy

I'm looking for an algorithm, which is a one-way function, like Hash function. And the algorithm accept a small input(serveral bits, less than 512 bits), and map it to a long output(1K Byte or more). Do you know an algorithm or a function like this?

Comment: you replicate every bit 10 times... ;-) no, honestly i cant see any reason to do this

Answer (score 4):

From the [Shannon theorem](http://www3.alcatel-lucent.com/bstj/vol28-1949/articles/bstj28-4-656.pdf) you don't gain any security by having a cyphertext of a size bigger than your plain text, unless the key (or the procedure to create the cyphertext) is different for any input. Even in this case, you will need to assign only one key (or mechanism) for each input `x`  otherwise you violate the definition of a function. So if you apply an encryption mechanism f: X (set of inputs) -> Y (set of outputs), then `|Y| <= |X|`.

All this to say that if your input is less than `512` bits, you gain nothing by producing a `1KB` output. Now, I recommend you to use one of the functions listed on the [one-way function wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I have a file(for example, 1M bits), and I use one or several one-way function with a 512 bits input to generate a 1M bits length data, then the 1M bits file XOR with the 1M bits data, can I treat the XOR result as a ciphertext?

Answer (score 2):

[Keccak](http://keccak.noekeon.org/) has variable length output, (although not evaluated for in SHA-3), it's "security claim is disentangled from the output length. There is a minimum output length..." and [Skein](http://www.skein-hash.info/about) hash function has a variable output of up to [16 exabytes](http://www.schneier.com/skein1.3.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your reasons are, you can calculate hashes of the same small data using different algorithms, then concatenate those hashes. If the output is not large enough, calculate hashes of hashes and append them.

As pointed in other answers, this doesn't have much sense from security perspective.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I have a file(for example, 1M bits), and I use one or several one-way function with a 512 bits input to generate a 1M bits length data, then the 1M bits file XOR with the 1M bits data, can I treat the XOR result as a ciphertext?

Comment: @perfectpei sounds like reinventing RC4 algorithm which is pretty similar to your idea. Also it sounds that the algorithm as I see it from your description can be reversed pretty easily. If you want comments on the algorithm you are trying to invent, http://crypto.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask.